# WP Не отображается кастомная рубрика для кастомного типа поста

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, создал кастомную таксономию вендоров

```
//
///*
// *  Регистрация таксономии производителей
// */

add_action( 'init', 'create_vendor_taxonomies' );

// функция, создающая таксономии "vendors" для постов типа "vendor"
function create_vendor_taxonomies(){

    // Добавляем недревовидную таксономию 'vendors' (как метки)
    register_taxonomy('vendors', array('vendor', 'post'), array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'labels'        => array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Производители', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Vendor', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Поиск производителей' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'Все производители' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Vendor' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Vendor:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Править производителя' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Обновить производителя' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Добавить нового производителя' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'Имя нового производителя' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Vendors' ),
        ),
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'show_in_rest'  => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
    ));
}
```

Создал кастомный тип записей Игры

```
/*
 *  Тип записей для производителей Тип записи Game
 */

function create_games_posttype() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Games', 'Тип записей Games', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Game', 'Тип записей game', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Games', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'Все игры', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'Обзор игры', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Добавить новую игру', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Добавить новую игру', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Редактировать игру', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Обновить игру', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Искать игру', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Не найдено', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Не найдено в корзине', 'bahisyasal' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'games', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'description' => __( 'Каталог игр', 'bahisyasal' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'vendors'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite'   => array(
            'slug' => 'vendors',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-buddicons-activity',
        'capability_type' => 'page',
    );

    register_post_type( 'games', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_games_posttype', 0 );
```

Хочу что бы для типа записи `games` можно б было выбрать производителя `vendors` ... Но почему-то не добавляется в настройках выбора нужной рубрики.
[image: WP проблема]

Не могу понять где я допускаю ошибку. Вот документация про [register_post_type](https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type)

Ну и собственно мне необходимо сделать корректные URL
Что-то по типу `https://mysite.loc/Blizzard-Entertainment/diablo-2` Прочитал что за это отвечает значение 'rewrite' надеюсь что ничего не напутал. Но почему не отображает vendors не понимаю. Прописал же строку `'taxonomies' => array('category', 'vendors'),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для того что таксономия появилась на странице создания/редактирования поста ее нужно добавить в параметры функции `register_taxonomy`

```
register_taxonomy('vendors', array('vendor', 'post', 'games'), array(
```

для отображения слага таксономии в ссылке нужно корректно указать параметр `rewrite`, например вот так

```
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => 'games/%vendors%',   // тип поста и сама таксономия
        'with_front' => false
    ],
```

Теперь нужно добавить хук, чтобы заменять %vendors% при получении ссылки на запись через функцию `get_permalink` и производные от нее функции:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'vendors_permalink', 1, 2 );

function vendors_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( strpos( $permalink, '%vendors%' ) === false ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'vendors' );
    
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) && is_object( $terms[0] ) ) {
        $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    } else{
        $taxonomy_slug = 'no-vendors';
    }
        
    return str_replace( '%vendors%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink );
}
```

в итоге у вас получится ссылка примерно такого вида:

```
https://mysite.loc/games/Blizzard-Entertainment/diablo-2
```

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, а как сократить URL до `https://mysite.loc/Blizzard-Entertainment/diablo-2`  Как убрать games из урла ?  И да, за вывод данного поста должен отвечать шаблон типа `single-games.php` или что-то другое ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 для этого вам нужно изменить параметр slug на вот такой 'slug' => '%vendors%', но я не уверен что это удачная идея. по шаблону все верно

Comment: Спасибо, теперь почему-то страница игры отображается, а все остальные   page-vendors.php single.php taxonomy-vendors.php стали вести на 404.  Может есть идея из-за чего это происходит ?  [![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/joXnB.jpg

Answer (score 1):

У тебя ошибка при регистрации таксономии. Нужно правильно указывать тип поста.

```
register_taxonomy('vendors', array('games', 'post')
```